# GLSL ES Write only a specific component

Tags: opengl-es

I have a deferred renderer where Im storing the compressed normals in an RGB8 texture, where only the R and G channel are used.

After the SSAO pass Im blurring the AO using a fullscreen quad and a FBO that is using the same render target where my normals are stored; but this time I want to write the B channel only; so Im using glColorMask(false,false,true,false) next; right after I bind my FBO and in my shader Im using gl_FragColor.b=my_blurred_ao. It seems to work for the first frame after right the FBO is created (or when I resize my window) but then my normals X&Y stored in the R&B channels get trashed...

What would cause this behavior? Am I missing something...

Comment: > What would cause this behavior? 

Calling glInvaludateFramebuffer() anywhere? Or a driver bug? It seems odd that window resize triggers it though, so I suspect possibly application logic. Hard to tell without at least some clue what your code looks like - any chance of a cut-down reproducer?